# how to detect certain ending words in a mention

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regular expression to detect mentions and extract them into string:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=^|\s)@([^@\s]+)/'
```

this works well for detecting strings like this:

```
@ajksdh
@kajshd123
@12398asdd
```

however I wanted to make an exception so that it doesn't detect mention strings that end with 'rb', so the following shouldn't be matched

```
@72rb
@80rb
```

so the format is some numbers followed by 'rb'. Is this even possible?

Comment: `(?<=^|\s)@(?![^@\s]+rb)([^@\s]+)`

Comment: By the way, as a regex maniac, I have to ask: `rb` doesn't stand for RegexBuddy (famous regex software) by any chance, does it?

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**

To exclude strings ending with `rb`, just add a closing boundary and a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<=^|\s)@([^@\s]+)(?<!rb)\b
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tN0aL3)

**Step 2**

What this is missing is that the `[^@\s]` does not really define what you want (I am guessing). At the moment, it is matching newlines, for instance, and Japanese characters. This is probably closer to what you want:

```
(?<=^|\s)@((?:(?!@)\w)+)(?<!rb)\b
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/lM4kD5)

Fine-Tuning

If instead of just `\w` you want to allow more characters, let me know which, and we can tune this. For instance, to allow all ASCII characters except space, we could use:

```
(?<=^|\s)@((?:(?!@)[!-~])+)(?<!rb)\b
```

Comment: What is `|\s` in your lookbehind means? But there isn't a space after `@` symbol.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I haven't touched the `(?<=^|\s)`, that is from adit's original regex. It is a do-it-yourself boundary: presumably, he wants to make sure that the `@` he matches is either preceded by a whitespace character or sits at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Hey adit, following up on this, did this answer solve it, or is the problem still troubling you?